# Input width not 100% (like specified)

Tags: html, css, width, parent-child

Could any of you please suggest a way of setting the width of a text input box so that it automatically adapts its parent's (.hero) width?

I can work my way around to resize the input boxes but they stop being responsive once I do.

```css
h9 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact {
  min-height: 130vh;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h10 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
}

.contact-text {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: gainsboro;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 90vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
}

.form {
  width: 200%;
}

.input-group {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

input,
textarea {
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

label {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  cursor: text;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 111%;
  min-width: 111%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:focus~label,
input:valid~label,
textarea:focus~label,
textarea:valid~label {
  top: -35px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact">
  <h9>Contact</h9>
  <div class="hero">
    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/galus.films@gmail.com" method="POST">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="name" required>
        <label for="name"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> Full Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="email" required>
        <label for="email"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i> Email Address</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="subject" required>
        <label for="subject"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i> Subject / Order No.</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <textarea style="resize: none;" id="message" rows="8" required></textarea>
        <label for="message"> Message </label><i class="fa-solid fa-message-text"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://galusfilms.com/contact">
      <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Why is input/textarea not filling in 100% of .hero's width?
.input group is centered with so much free space around it, why is this happening?

I'm kinda new to this so I would really appreciate some help...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a label to create a placeholder for the input, there's a specific attribute for it. (If you wanna insert the icon, use the Unicode)

If you wanna make the inputs touch the border of the container play around with the padding.

```css
.hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.form {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

input,
textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <form action="https://formsubmit.co/galus.films@gmail.com" method="POST" class="form">
    <input type="text" id="name" required placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" id="email" required placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" id="subject" required placeholder="Subject">
    <textarea style="resize: none;" id="message" rows="8" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://galusfilms.com/contact">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: But this way I am not able to add that label:focus animation, right?